# Chow lemma + resolution of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to understand the following simple reduction in Deligne's *Theorie de Hodge II*. He works in the category of schemes of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$.

Let $f : X \to S$ be a proper smooth morphism with $S$ smooth, separated and connected. He claims that, by Chow's lemma and resolution of singularities, there exists a quasi-projective and smooth $X'$ and a projective birational morphism $p : X' \to X$. Then by Bertini or Sard there exists an open subset $S_0 \subset S$ such that the base change of $f' = f\circ p$ along $S_0 \hookrightarrow S$, $f'_0 : X'_0 \to X_0 \to S_0$, is smooth. Further, he claims $f'_0$ is projective.

Can someone explain the application of Chow's lemma and resolution of singularities more explicitly? According to the statement of Chow's lemma that I found, one gets a *proper* birational map to $X$. And from the statement of Hironaka's resolution of singularities I found, one gets another proper birational map to that.  So I don't understand how Deligne can assume $p$ is projective.  And I don't see why $X'$ is quasi-projective (over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$, I guess he means).

More importantly, even under these assumptions I don't understand why $f'_0$ is projective. And I don't think the base change to $S_0$ has anything to do with it; it's probably true that $f' : X' \to X \to S$ is projective.

I understand these facts are obvious to algebraic geometers, but I would really appreciate an explanation for a beginner to scheme theory.

Comment: I think you must have misread the statement of Chow's lemma.  You do get a projective morphisms.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: could you point me to a reference?  I was looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%27s_lemma and http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O2.

Comment: You can see Chow's Lemma in Section 5.6 of EGA II.